# Need form to use multiple submit buttons

Tags: php, jquery, forms, postgresql, insert-update

I have a form that I would like to have display two versions of the data.  I know that I can set two variables for this, but I can't figure out how to get it to insert into the postgres db.  I have gotten as far populating the data and having the labels to enter in the new numbers for insertion into the table.

Here's what I have so far ...

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    <?
    $yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));
    if ($_REQUEST['start'] == '') {
        $_REQUEST['stores'] = array(1,2,3,7,8,9,17,18,19,23,16,11,4,5,6);
        $_REQUEST['start'] = $yesterday;
    } else {
        $_REQUEST['stores'] = array(1,2,3,7,8,9,17,18,19,23,16,11,4,5,6);
    }
    $_REQUEST['submit'] = 'Get Data'; 
    ?>
}

</script>

<?
// various arrays and db connections we're going to need later 
include('/home/...some_data_goes_here.../db_connect.inc');

$dbx = DB::connect('******');
$dbx->setFetchMode(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

//get the data based on the date.
$start = $_REQUEST['start'];

//$stores = array(1 => '1,177,18', 2 => '2,277,28', 3 => '3,377,38', 7 => '4,477,48', 8 => '5,577,58', 18 => '338', 19 => '50,51', 9 => '6,677,68', 17 => '8,877,818', 16 => '44,45,47', 11 => '7,770,78', 4 => '11,15,17', 5 => '22,25,27', 6 => '33,35,37');

$formstores = $_REQUEST['stores'];

foreach($stores as $sid => $pcs) {
    $store_name = $db->getOne('SELECT store_name FROM stores WHERE store_id = ?', array($sid));
}

foreach($formstores as $k => $sid) {

        if(empty($storeDataMain)){ //array is empty so make one
            $storeDataMain = array();
        }

        //get the store names
        $store_name = $db->getOne('SELECT store_name FROM stores WHERE store_id = ?', array($sid));
        if(DB::isError($store_name)) { echo '<div class="error">Error '.$store_name->getdebuginfo().'</div>'; return; }

        $tempups = $db->getOne('SELECT sum(count) FROM traffic WHERE store_id = ? AND tdate = ?', array($sid,$start));
        //echo $tempups .' | ';
        if(DB::isError($tempups)) { echo '<div class="error">Error '.$tempups->getdebuginfo().'</div>'; return; }
        $tups = $tempups/2;
        //echo $tups;

        //Build array out and return it 
        $storeDataMain[$store_name] = array('trafficGuests' => number_format(floatval($tups),1,'.',',')); // floatval prevents the numbers from rounding to zero
}   
?>

<h3 class="heading">Traffic Updates</h3>
<p>Enter dates in yyyy-mm-dd format.</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/css/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/css/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/css/datepicker.js"></script>
<form name="setTraffic" method="get" action="/traffic/updateTraffic.php">

<!-- Build the table where they can input the date to be changed -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="start" id="start" value="<?=$_REQUEST['start']?>" alt="mm/dd/yyyy" onblur="if(this.value.length){valid=check_date(this.value);if(!valid){this.value='';this.focus();alert('Invalid date input');}else{this.value=valid;}}" onchange="if(this.value.length){valid=check_date(this.value);if(!valid){this.value='';this.focus();alert('Invalid date input');}else{this.value=valid;}}" onfocus="if(this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = ''" /></td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                                var start_picker = new DatePicker({
                                    relative    : 'start',
                                    language    : 'en',
                                    dateFormat  : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                    showDuration: 0.1,
                                    closeEffectDuraction: 0.1,
                                    disableFutureDate: true,
                                    disablePastDate: false,
                                    keepFieldEmpty : true
                                });
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Data" id="submit" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="height: 20px; width: 165px; vertical-align: bottom;">Stores</th>
                <? //build the list of stores for the headers.
                    foreach($storeDataMain as $k => $val){
                        echo '<th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:   bottom;">'.$k.'</th>';
                    }
                ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="height: 20px; vertical-align: bottom;">Guests for <?=$start?>    </th>
                <? //format and print out the traffic for each store
                    foreach($storeDataMain as $k => $val){
                    echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; font-size: 14px;">'.$val["trafficGuests"].'</td>';
                } 
            ?>
    </tr>  


    <tr>
        <th style="height: 20px; vertical-align: bottom;">Adjustment for <?=$start?></th>
        <? //build the input fields identified based on store id.
                foreach($formstores as $pcs) {
                    echo '<td><input class="newTraffic" type="number" style="width: 65px; text-align: right;" name="new_count" id="'.$pcs.'" value="'.$count.'" />'.$count.'</td>';
                    <script>// get the data ready for inserting into the database
                        if(isset($count)){
                            $count = $_POST['']
                        } else {
                            $count = '';
                        }}

                        if( $_POST ){
                            $count = $_POST["count"];
                            $store_id = $sid

                        $insertCounts = $db->query('INSERT INTO traffic (store_id, thour, tdate, count, door) VALUES ('$sid', )');
                    }
                }
                </script>

                }
            ?>
        </tr>      
    </table>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>


<h5 style="color: #707070;">New Traffic Counts</h5>
<table style="color: #707070;">
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 20px; width: 165px; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: bottom;">Stores</td>
            <? //display the list of stores for the output of the new counts.
                    foreach($storeDataMain as $k => $val){
                        echo '<td style="text-align: center; width: 69px; padding: 4px; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: bottom;">'.$k.'</td>';
                    }
                ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 20px; vertical-align: bottom; font-weight: bold;">Guests for <?=$start?></td>
                <? //format and display the NEW traffic for each store
                    foreach($storeDataMain as $k => $val){
                        $newCount = $val["trafficGuests"] + $count[$pcs];
                        echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; font-size: 14px;">'.$newCount.'</td>';
                    } 
                ?>
        </tr> 
</table>
</form>
```

If you'd like to see what the page looks like you can go [here] (https://picasaweb.google.com/105736785937866961668/January22013#5828892865441021874) and the inputs are designed to take in the adjustment to the number, whether it's positive or negative.  From there it is inserted into the DB table and added to the existing sum so that the new total can be reflected in the bottom greyed out table.

I know that this is something that may not be able to be accomplished, but if it can't I need to be able to get to the point where my data will still be entered into the table and then reflected after submit.  I just can't seem to get there with my existing knowledge of code.

**Please help?!**

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on a question yet, but I think there are a few issues with your php.  as @Anubis points out the insert statement needs work.  Also, the first few lines of actual php code look like they are wrapped in a javascript event for the window loading.  This is not needed as the code doesn't produce any javascript to run.  This code will be run on the server during every page load anyway.  There are a few other places you have `<script>` tags that are not needed and probably cause some errors.

I think what you want is to do is add an identifier to your post fields to help get the correct values.  So when you are building your input boxes do it like this:

```
echo '<td><input class="newTraffic" type="number" style="width: 65px; text-align: right;" name="new_count__'.$pcs.'" id="'.$pcs.'" value="'.$count.'" />'.$count.'</td>';
```

And access the submitted values as follows: `$_POST['new_count__' . $pcs]`

You are trying to integrate two separate processes which makes your code hard to follow and more error prone.  I see what you are trying to do but try putting input processing code at the top and display code towards the bottom. So in rough code/comments:

```
<?php //check for and process the new data
    //if posted values
    //process $_POST for values to add/subtract
    //if(isset($_POST)) {
    //if(!empty($_POST) {
    switch ($_POST['submit']) {
        case 'submit':
            //new date selected
            //get new display data
            break;
        case 'submit2':
            //new traffic counts submitted
            //for each input submitted
            //add/subtract value to current database traffic value
            //get new display data
            break;
        default:
            //stuff if no submit
            //get default display data
    }

?>

<html>
    display html data here
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is wrong:

```
//, thour, tdate, count, door <- are there default values defined for theses? if not set the values
$db->query('INSERT INTO traffic (store_id) VALUES ('.$sid.')');
```

while programming you should use this error settings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

this gives you lots of errors and descriptions when something goes wrong and it makes debugging easier.

in a production environment "display_errors" should be 0!